# How to pass more than one parameter to xpath expression

Tags: selenium, xpath, robotframework

I have got a situation, where I have to input multiple arguments to a keyword (in a selenium robotframework testcase) and the keyword has to take each argument separately to test the keyword related xpath.

The keyword is developed in such a way that It can take only one argument. Can you please help me how to resolve the issue?? I appreciate your help..

Keyword1 has an xpath where it can take only parameter. If I input only one parameter keyword1 is passing. But If I want to input morethan one argument to the xpath ( I tried to do it mention "@{data}" as an argument to the keyword and accordingly mentioning the data to the testcase keyword. I thought xpath would take each argument separately and would execute the keyword, but instead it took all the data and tried to execute it). is there any way that I could execute the test case, without using the keyword multiple times but using the arguments manytimes in the test case?

Thank You,
Yogi..

Comment: Can you post some code and try to reframe your question as your question is not at all clear. Also read this for help - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Update your reusable function to accept variable arguments, then use String.format function to replace variable arguments.

```
 String.format("//%s[@id=%s","a","anchor-id")
```

In this way you can send multiple arguments to be replaced in xpath